# Angular JS Debug Logs

Tags: angularjs, logging

I wrote few logs in my angular js application using the code below. However I am unable to see it displayed either in the console or (chrome -> dev tools) browser console. Where can I see the logs displayed?

```
    console.info(' Maintanence !! ');
    console.info(' Next Event = '+ next.name);
```

Comment: where exactly is this code placed in your angular app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `console.log('Maintanence !!');`

Comment: Thanks Max. I tried that as well , but didn't see it printed. Maybe that block of code is not executed. I will retry and update.

Comment: Thanks , it is printing.